# Is it possible to list/read emails in Windows Phone 7 using Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm wondering if it is possible to list/read emails from Silverlight app in Windows Phone 7 environment. I know that I can create new SMS/emails, but I'd like to actually parse incoming emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible.

Here are the tasks available:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(v=VS.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In the interests of the security of the users data and information. Windows Phone 7 does not allow third party applications access to emails.

The only thing that a Silverlight application can do with regard to emails is to: [allow the user to select an email address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailaddresschoosertask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) from one of their contacts; and to [launch the email composer task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).